# Facebook like button in fancybox

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, fancybox

The content of my FancyBox is loaded by ajax .
In this content I have some social button (like, tweet, +1). But I have a problem with the like button, normally when you click over a popover is displayed for we offer different options to share, but in my case it is not displayed completely [image].

I wish that popover appears on the outside of fancybox to display in full, as google+

[image]

How to do ?

Comment: For the moment I still have not found a solution, I just added "overflow: hidden" to my facebook button to display the bug does not appear